# TWRP not detecting external storage, shown as 0MB

Tags: external-sd, twrp

I have managed to install TWRP using Odin on my Samsung Galaxy Note 2 (GT-N7100). Installed TWRP version `twrp-2.8.7.0-t03g.img.tar`. It is showing External Sdcard (0MB).

Why is that so? Can anyone help me out?

Comment: 1. Try mounting external storage from the 'Mount' menu (if it's not mounted) OR 2. **You flashed a recovery of some other variant of your phone.**

Comment: @GokulNC Samsung galaxy note 2 comes with 2 variants GTN7100 and GTN7105 this TWRP version is compatiable with Both of the version as per this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a7z8W6b2CrQ .

Answer (score 0):

Use a smaller SD card.  TWRP does not work with exfat formatted partitions at least on a T210R

Answer (score 0):

Format your memory card to FAT32 that should solve the issue. Also you are using an older version of TWRP for your device. Latest version can be found here [TWRP for Samsung Galaxy Note 2 N7100](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-note-2/orig-development/recovery-t3589010)